# How can I change the number of vertices in surface mesh?

Tags: vertices

I created a surface mesh in itksnap with stl format. I can import it to blender. Please consider it with 3000 vertices and 1700 facets.  At now I want to change the number of vertices to 2200. How can I do it?

Shahrokh

Comment: You can use the Decimate Modifier, as described, but also X > Limited Dissolve, and/or W > Remove Doubles... with both these two solutions you can play with the parameters on the bottom of the left menu (activated with N)

Answer (score 1):

### Reduce the number of vertices with the decimate modifier

1. Add a decimate modifier to the object and set it to **collapse**.
2. In the ratio field, enter `desired amount / current amount`.
3. If needed, apply the modifier.

[image]